# How to crop windows (not images) under Linux?

Tags: window-manager, window-management

Is there any method, e.g perhaps a specific window manager, that has the ability to crop windows?

I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04, but am flexible...

Setup: I use "alt click" to move windows, and "alt right click" to resize windows.

Example: One might wish to have a small window, e.g BBC live news, or a youtube video, or a long running terminal process, visible in one corner of the monitor.

Seeking a way to crop an application's window, so that only the desired part of the application is visible - in exactly the same way one would crop an image - only cropping a live running window instead.

I suspect an alternative window manager would be required.

Comment: As a workaround you can watch videos with [mpv](http://mpv.io/).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know of mpv - just checked it looks great, will replace vlc with mpv for local videos. Though, I don't think (?) it will solve this particular issue as most videos in this context are live streams from various websites...

Comment: mpv uses youtube-dl as default for livestreams. youtube-dl supports a [hundreds of websites](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/tree/master/youtube_dl/extractor).

Comment: Excellent! Thankyou for the tip!

Comment: For those interested: this works well, at least for videos. You can either just drop URL's directly onto the mpv window, or run: `youtube-dl -o - "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PB2OegI6wvI" | mpv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be using [Xephyr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xephyr) to run a separate X server in a window. You can then run applications in that server (by setting the `DISPLAY` environment variable), move them to be partially off-screen, and resize the Xephyr window.

Example:

```
$ Xephyr +extension RANDR -screen 800x600 -ac -br -softCursor -resizeable :1
$ export DISPLAY=:1
$ kwin &  # I use KDE, run the window manager in that server too
$ firefox --no-remote --ProfileManager  # Run a separate instance of Firefox
```

Here's the result, a cropped Firefox showing this page, on top of a Firefox in my main server showing the same page (I purposefully left part of the Firefox URL bar visible, but you could adjust to only show part of the page):

[image: screenshot of Xephyr window]

Use ctrl+shift to toggle mouse and keyboard grabbing so that alt+click will move the nested window instead of the Xephyr window.

If you're using kwin or something similar, you might have options to remove the title and borders from the Xephyr window (right click on window title > More Actions > Configure Special Window Settings):

[image: screenshot of kwin options]

Allowing you a true cropped window (example here over a black background):

[image: screenshot of cropped Xephyr window with no title bar or borders]